# Intervals partitioning: minimum overlap

Tags: optimization, set-partition

Suppose there are intervals in the format of `r = (start, end)`, and `D = {r1, r2, ..., rn)`.

Now we would like to partition `D` into several partitions (let's say `m`) where each partition has roughly similar size (`n/m`), and the overlap between partitions is minimum.

The overlap between partition $p_i$ and $p_j$ is defined as $f(p_i, p_j) = \max\{0, \min\{p_i.end, p_j.end\} - \max\{p_i.start, p_j.start\}$

where $p_i.start$ and $p_i.end$ are the leftmost and rightmost endpoints in $p_i$. Similar definition for $p_j$.

Is there any solution?

If there is no any two intervals overlapping each other, I have a heuristic method: sort these intervals, and split them (every `n/m` is a partition). But I do not know the correctness of this method.

Comment: "each partition has roughly similar size" is not mathematically well-defined. Maybe you want to add some context to explain why this is important?

Comment: @supinf to make it simple, assume n can be divided evenly by m.

Comment: As supinf notes, the “roughly similar size” criteria isn’t well-defined. Furthermore, you also want to minimize overlap, which turns this into a multiobjective optimization problem. Can you clarify what exactly your objective is?